# Can't update PlayReady in Windows Media Center

Tags: windows-8, windows-media-center

In WMC I am only getting the channels that also go OTA, like ABC, NBC, etc. The cable channels are just black screens.

Once in a while this error pops up:
[image: The PlayReady update was incomplete. You will not be able to watch or record protected content until the update is successful.]

But immediately after clicking update it fails, asks to try again, and gets stuck in this pattern.

How can I update PlayReady?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the PlayReady Runtime 1.3.1 manually from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2754708).